# How to Control Numato Ethernet Relay Module

Tags: c#, tcp, module, telnet, ethernet

I have winforms application in c# and 8 channel numato ethernet relay module, I am able to connect using telnet using this library *https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library* with this defualt credential ip : 169.254.1.1
port: 23
un : admin
pw : admin
the problem is that when I send the command nothing happens.

here is the full code of the telnet lib.

```
// minimalistic telnet implementation
// conceived by Tom Janssens on 2007/06/06  for codeproject
//
// http://www.corebvba.be



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MinimalisticTelnet
{
    enum Verbs {
        WILL = 251,
        WONT = 252,
        DO = 253,
        DONT = 254,
        IAC = 255
    }

    enum Options
    {
        SGA = 3
    }

    class TelnetConnection
    {
        TcpClient tcpSocket;

        int TimeOutMs = 100;

        public TelnetConnection(string Hostname, int Port)
        {
            tcpSocket = new TcpClient(Hostname, Port);

        }

        public string Login(string Username,string Password,int LoginTimeOutMs)
        {
            int oldTimeOutMs = TimeOutMs;
            TimeOutMs = LoginTimeOutMs;
            string s = Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
               throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no login prompt");
            WriteLine(Username);

            s += Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no password prompt");
            WriteLine(Password);

            s += Read();
            TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
            
            return s;
        }

        public void WriteLine(string cmd)
        {
            Write(cmd + "\n");
            
        }

        public void Write(string cmd)
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
            byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF","\0xFF\0xFF"));
            tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            do
            {
                ParseTelnet(sb);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
            } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get { return tcpSocket.Connected; }
        }

        void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                switch (input)
                {
                    case -1 :
                        break;
                    case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                        // interpret as command
                        int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                        if (inputverb == -1) break;
                        switch (inputverb)
                        {
                            case (int)Verbs.IAC: 
                                //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                                sb.Append(inputverb);
                                break;
                            case (int)Verbs.DO: 
                            case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                            case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                            case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                                // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                                int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                                if (inputoption == -1) break;
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                                if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA )
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL:(byte)Verbs.DO); 
                                else
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT); 
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        sb.Append( (char)input );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my form load code to connect to the device

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MinimalisticTelnet;  


TelnetConnection tc;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            tc = new TelnetConnection("169.254.1.1", 23);
            string s = tc.Login("admin", "admin", 100);
            textBox1.Text = s;
        }
```

button code to send command

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                       
            if (tc.IsConnected)
            {
                tc.WriteLine("relay on 0");
                textBox2.Text = tc.Read();                                
            }                     
        }
```

Comment: a) Check manual if you are using the correct newline character. b) Make sure you are sending what you actually _expect_ to send. c) Check if the device actually reacts to any command (is there an "echo" or "info" or something like that, so you can simply test responsiveness of the device?) d) I wouldn't rely on `.Available` just parse as long as stream.Read >= 0 , but that means you need a dedicated thread and probably need to change some of the design. So, I'd check the other things first.

Comment: this comment helps me a lot realizing that   Write(cmd + "\n"); needs to be   Write(cmd + "\r\n"); and anything works thanks a lot @fildor